# Changed Apache configurations, now localhost/~username/index.php throws 403 Error

Tags: permissions, apache2, localhost

I have been struggling to get laravel php framework up and running on my mac with yosemite. I have made changes to both the httpd.conf file in /etc/apache2 as well as my user config file username.conf. Now after changing it back I get a 403 "Forbidden You don't have permission to access /~username/my_phpinfo.php on this server." Also I should not that I am using Apache/2.4.9. This is the user conf file I currently have:

```
<Directory "/Users/<username>/Sites/">
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I also feel like possible errors could be in this section (line number~=238) of the httpd.conf file:

```
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
MultiviewsMatch Any

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride all

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```